# In Mongodb , how do I check if all the documents are unique for a value?

Tags: mongodb, unique, database

Let's say I have 4 documents in the database:

```
{ name: 'alex' }
{ name: 'jen' }
{ name: 'alex' }
{ name: 'john'}
```

In MongoDB Shell, I want to know if **2 or more documents share the same 'name'**.

Basically, if all the names are different, return true. 
If 2 or people have the same name, return false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, uses a quick [map-reduce query](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) to find the number of documents that have the same name, and returns true if they're all different:

```
function allDifferent() {
    var m = function() { emit(this.name, 1); }
    var r = function(key, emits) {
        var n = 0; emits.forEach(function(v) { n += v; }); return n;
    }
    var result = db.mycol.mapReduce(m, r, { out: "namecounts" });
    var allDifferent= (db.namecounts.count( { value: { $gt: 1 } } ) == 0)
    db.namecounts.drop();
    return allDifferent;
}
```