# finding duplicates using map reduce from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to find the duplicates in a collection in mongo db which has around 20000 documents. The result should give me the key (on which I am grouping) and the count of times they are repeated only if the count is greater than 1. The below is not complete, however it is giving an error also when I run in mongo.exe shell :

```
db.runCommand({ mapreduce: users, 
 map : function Map() {
                emit(this.emailId, 1); 
}
reduce : function Reduce(key, vals) {
                return Array.sum(vals);

}
finalize : function Finalize(key, reduced) {
                return reduced
}
out : { inline : 1 }
});
```

SyntaxError: missing } after property list (shell):5

why is the above error coming?
how can only get the ones with count greater than 1?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102918/in-mongodb-how-do-i-check-if-all-the-documents-are-unique-for-a-value/7103581#7103581

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is an exact copy of the code you've entered, but it looks like you're missing commas between the fields in the object being passed to `runCommand`. Try:

```
db.runCommand({ mapreduce: users, 
    map : function Map() {
        emit(this.emailId, 1); 
    },
    reduce : function Reduce(key, vals) {
        return Array.sum(vals);
    },
    finalize : function Finalize(key, reduced) {
        return reduced
    },
    out : { inline : 1 }
});
```

Also note that even when using `finalize`, you can't actually remove entries from the outputted document (or collection) in a single-pass with Map-Reduce. However, whether you're using `out: {inline: 1}`, or `out: "some_collection"`, it is pretty trivial to filter out results where the count is 1.