# MongoDB: how do I check that all array entries are unique in the entire collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

A little brainteaser for mongo users.

I have a collection of documents like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("19628f4f0545a733185b672f"),
    "name" : "hello",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "itemNumber" : 12512,
            "value" : "let"
        }, 
        {
            "itemNumber" : 2546,
            "value" : "put"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to make sure that every item's `itemNumber` is unique globally in the collection.

In SQL database I would have a separate table for items and the query for checking if numbers are unique would be something like

```
select count(1) 
from (
   select itemNumber, count(itemNumber) as cnt 
   from items 
   group by itemNumber) sel 
where cnt>1;
```

Resulting `0` would mean that all `itemNumber`s are unique. (Probably there are better ways to make that check in SQL)

With MongoDB the only solution that I can come to is

a) use `forEach` to extract all items to separate collection

b) make a simple aggregation

```
db.items.aggregate(
    { $group : { _id : '$itemNumber', count : {$sum : 1} } },
    { $out : "cnt" }
)
```

c) `db.cnt.find({count: {$gt: 1}}).count()`

Is there any one-query way to do it?

Performace notice: the collection is about 3M documents, 2,2KB each. I have noticed that aggreations that contain `$group` run like forever on this collection.

Comment: Possible solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102918/in-mongodb-how-do-i-check-if-all-the-documents-are-unique-for-a-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like that:

```
db.items.aggregate(
    { $unwind: "$items" }    ,
    { $group : { _id : '$items.itemNumber', count : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $match: { "count": { $gt: 1 } } }
)
```